# make only one bold letter in a word ionic-angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I would like to know how to set only a specific letter inside a word, in my case the first one, in angularJS. For example, I have an array of words like :

```
var Words = [Mon,Tue,Wed];
```

I want to show the first letter of every element bold and the rest of word with normal font.

Comment: I think your question has a fundamental flaw in that this is not problem for AngularJS to solve but rather a fairly simple CSS issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having you first letter bold is purely visual, so it should not be reflected in your HTML but purely managed by CSS. This is important for accessibility and usability of our text, also respect [HTML semantics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML)

> CSS is used to suggest its presentation to human users.

There is a property called `::first-letter (:first-letter)` which work very well and is [very well describe on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

> The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element selects the first letter of the
>   first line of a block, if it is not preceded by any other content
>   (such as images or inline tables) on its line.

Here is an exemple of CSS

```
p:first-letter {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And a JSFiddle to perform some test : http://jsfiddle.net/mtjzsh5v/

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: This is the correct way to approach the original problem, rather than using scripting.

Comment: Absolutely elegant solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In the view, of course:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in Words">
    <b>{{value.substring(0,1)}}</b>{{value.substring(1)}}
</div>
```

Comment: Having you first letter bold is purely visual, so it should not be reflected in your HTML but purely managed by CSS. This is important for accessibility and usability of our text, so I don't really like this option.

Comment: So, you should ask then for CSS solution.

Comment: Agree in principle with @sebastienbarbier but the OP did specifically ask for an AngularJS solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

**Using ::first-letter**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="Word in Words">
           <p>
             {{Word}}
           </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/twvy0j4a/9/

---

If you want to bold entire word then you can use **ng-if** like this

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/twvy0j4a/8/

---

**Html:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="Word in Words">
           <span ng-if="$index === 0" class="bold">{{Word}}- {{$index}}</span>
        <span ng-if="$index !== 0" class="preview">{{Word}}- {{$index}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.Words = ['Mon','Tue','Wed'];
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.bold{

    font-weight:bold;
}
```